# Android Map Activity crashes when leaving Activity [Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)]

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm developing and Android app that uses Google Maps. When I leave the Map Activity it crashes, other things work well. I'm using Android Studio and Android Virtual Device.

I tested the app on a real device and nothing happens, so it must be something wrong with the emulator.

This is the error:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xb84a396c (code=2), thread 2045 (Thread-131)
```

I showed the app to my boss, but he wants me to proove it is an emulator's bug, I told him but he wants documentation to proove this from an acredited source or something like that, or to fix this error.

**EDIT**
This is the logcat:

```
07-25 16:20:12.380      383-662/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.geopath/.HistorialActivity} from pid 1307
07-25 16:20:12.390      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-25 16:20:12.390      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
07-25 16:20:13.390    1307-1307/com.example.geopath W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-25 16:20:14.110      383-397/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.geopath/.HistorialActivity: +1s660ms


07-25 16:20:14.840    1307-1358/com.example.geopath A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 1358 (Thread-113)
07-25 16:20:15.000        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-25 16:20:15.000        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic:4.4.2/KK/1246540:eng/test-keys'
07-25 16:20:15.000        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
07-25 16:20:15.010        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 1307, tid: 1358, name: Thread-113  >>> com.example.geopath <<<
07-25 16:20:15.010        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004



07-25 16:20:15.530        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 b8020ac0  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
07-25 16:20:15.530        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 00000000  r5 b6f14190  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
07-25 16:20:15.540        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 b8065ee0  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp 00000000
07-25 16:20:15.540        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 00000005  sp a675cd10  lr ac2f1737  pc 00000004  cpsr a8000030
07-25 16:20:15.540        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  42b4000000000000  d1  4183b118c2b40000
07-25 16:20:15.540        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2  4183b118c7296834  d3  bf73333000000000
07-25 16:20:15.550        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4  000000004080cccd  d5  43700000c09f3333
07-25 16:20:15.560        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6  3f8000003f800000  d7  3d4ccd0000000000
07-25 16:20:15.560        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
07-25 16:20:15.560        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
07-25 16:20:15.560        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
07-25 16:20:15.560        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
07-25 16:20:15.560        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 20000011
07-25 16:20:15.580        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
07-25 16:20:15.580        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00000004  <unknown>
07-25 16:20:15.580        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 00007735  /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-25 16:20:15.590        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 0000f06d  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglReleaseThread+44)
07-25 16:20:15.590        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 0000d538  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:20:15.590        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 0000ec78  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_exit+80)
07-25 16:20:15.590        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
07-25 16:20:15.590        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
07-25 16:20:15.590        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccd0  00000000
07-25 16:20:15.590        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccd4  a675cd44  [stack:1358]
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccd8  00000000
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccdc  b5aac323  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+346)
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cce0  b6e85df0  /system/lib/libbinder.so
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cce4  b8067da0  [heap]
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cce8  00000000
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccec  abb25fc3  /system/lib/libOpenglSystemCommon.so (HostConnection::get()+6)
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccf0  b8065ee0  [heap]
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccf4  00000000
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccf8  00000000
07-25 16:20:15.600        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccfc  00000000
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd00  00000000
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd04  00000000
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd08  b6f14190
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd0c  ac2f1715  /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  a675cd10  b6f12510  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  a675cd10  b6f12510  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd14  b6ed811f  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+50)
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd18  b6f10000  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd1c  b8067da0  [heap]
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd20  b8067da0  [heap]
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd24  00000000
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd28  b6e783ed  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::threadDestructor(void*))
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd2c  b6ed4afd  /system/lib/libc.so (free+12)
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd30  b8067d68  [heap]
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd34  b6f12320  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd38  b6e783ed  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::threadDestructor(void*))
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd3c  b6cb8de8  /system/lib/libEGL.so
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd40  b6f12328  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd44  b6c7c041  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglReleaseThread)
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd48  b7fc7628  [heap]
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd4c  b6f12510  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  a675cd60  00000019
07-25 16:20:15.610        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd64  b6ed453c  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r5:
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14170 b80dd5b8 00200000 00000502 0687ef68
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14180 00000000 00000000 b6f14180 b6f14180
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14190 b6f14188 b6f14188 b7f939c0 b8020ac0
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f141a0 b8016120 b8016120 b7fcb938 b808aa80
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f141b0 b7f8ee00 b8073f80 b8058210 b801b3a8
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f141c0 b7f1eae8 b7f1eae8 b8081bc8 b7f94b68
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f141d0 b8058a18 b8058a18 b7fb72d8 b7fb72d8
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f141e0 b7febfd8 b8030948 b7f8e9d8 b7f8e9d8
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f141f0 b7ff3440 b80244b0 b8031720 b80801f8
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14200 b7f1ecd0 b7f1ecd0 b8084398 b8080d40
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14210 b80457f0 b80457f0 b80587f0 b80587f0
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14220 b80323f0 b80323f0 b8051e88 b8051e88
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14230 b80587d8 b80587d8 b7f1ec98 b7f1ec98
07-25 16:20:15.710        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14240 b7fb7270 b7fb7270 b8016150 b8016150
07-25 16:20:15.730        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14250 b80670a8 b80670a8 b7ff4348 b7ff4348
07-25 16:20:15.740        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b6f14260 b8018e48 b8018e48 b8058980 b8058980
07-25 16:20:15.740        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r8:
07-25 16:20:15.740        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065ec0 00000001 00000001 b8065d98 00000000
07-25 16:20:15.740        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065ed0 00000001 b6ea7958 00000020 00000013
07-25 16:20:15.740        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065ee0 b7f1eb40 00000000 576caa20 00000073
07-25 16:20:15.740        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065ef0 de321475 0000006c 00000002 73726563
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f00 00000038 00000001 00000001 41980000
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f10 3f800000 00000000 3f800000 00000000
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f20 00000000 3f800000 00000000 00000000
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f30 ff000000 00005959 01060001 616e6472
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f40 00000018 00000001 0000000a 4c2d6e65
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f50 2d6e7461 00005355 00000001 0000002b
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f60 616a4c5b 6e2f6176 4e2f7465 6f777465
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f70 6e496b72 66726574 3b656361 00000000
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f80 00000000 0000001b af54d720 0000001c
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065f90 00000000 00000000 00000001 0000013b
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065fa0 b7e4f360 00000000 00000000 00130013
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ b8065fb0 00009800 00009800 00000480 fffffec0
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sp:
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675ccf0 b8065ee0 00000000 00000000 00000000
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd00 00000000 00000000 b6f14190 ac2f1715
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd10 b6f12510 b6ed811f b6f10000 b8067da0
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd20 b8067da0 00000000 b6e783ed b6ed4afd
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd30 b8067d68 b6f12320 b6e783ed b6cb8de8
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd40 b6f12328 b6c7c041 b7fc7628 b6f12510
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd50 b6f122c8 a675cdd0 b6f122c8 b6c7c06f
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd60 00000019 b6ed453c b5afb500 00000002
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd70 00000004 b6f122c8 00000001 b8045df0
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd80 00000000 00000000 000fe000 a665f000
07-25 16:20:15.750        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cd90 a665f000 be8c2644 b6f122c4 b6ed5c7c
07-25 16:20:15.780        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cda0 a675cdd0 b8045df0 b5aa0f8d b8045998
07-25 16:20:15.780        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cdb0 b5aa0f8d b8045df0 a675cdd0 00000011
07-25 16:20:15.780        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cdc0 00000078 b5aa0f8d be8c2644 b6ed41fc
07-25 16:20:15.810        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cdd0 a675cdd0 b8045df0 00000000 b6cc0844
07-25 16:20:15.820        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ a675cde0 b8065ee0 a5bd38b2 00000000 00000000
07-25 16:20:15.820        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
07-25 16:20:15.820        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.820        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.820        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.820        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.830        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.830        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.830        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.830        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.830        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.830        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.840        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.850        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.850        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.860        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.870        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.870        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-25 16:20:15.870        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
07-25 16:20:15.880        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1714 b9404603 20064983 44794a83 447a9305
07-25 16:20:15.880        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1724 e92cf7fd 464be7e6 c048f8d0 46524659
07-25 16:20:15.880        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1734 468147e0 4d7db9d8 4a7d2006 4c7d447d
07-25 16:20:15.880        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1744 4629447a f7fd447c f7fde91a 497ae966
07-25 16:20:15.890        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1754 44794a7a 91039400 0406f243 94024629
07-25 16:20:15.890        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1764 4603447a 30b7f240 20069001 2c00e7bd
07-25 16:20:15.890        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1774 69a3d033 2b0260e6 61276826 3080f446
07-25 16:20:15.890        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1784 46286020 f7fdd114 6b26e960 634cf8c0
07-25 16:20:15.890        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1794 f7fd4628 6b62e95a 91082100 46069207
07-25 16:20:15.890        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f17a4 90096be0 f7ffa807 f506fe8b e0337054
07-25 16:20:15.900        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f17b4 e950f7fd f8c06b21 46281498 e94af7fd
07-25 16:20:15.900        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f17c4 22006be3 93099208 6b604606 a8079007
07-25 16:20:15.900        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f17d4 fe76f7ff 409cf206 f8d8e01e 46281000
07-25 16:20:15.900        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f17e4 2a02698a f7fdd10c f8c0e930 4628434c
07-25 16:20:15.900        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f17f4 e92af7fd 94099408 f5009407 e00b7054
07-25 16:20:15.900        48-48/? I/DEBUG﹕ ac2f1804 e928f7fd 4498f8c0 f7fd4628 9408e924
07-25 16:20:17.570      383-447/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 889K, 23% free 6809K/8772K, paused 178ms, total 189ms
07-25 16:20:17.630      383-405/system_process I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
07-25 16:20:17.670     383-1388/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.geopath/.HistorialActivity
07-25 16:20:17.940      383-405/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 119K, 20% free 7052K/8772K, paused 149ms, total 150ms
07-25 16:20:17.940      383-405/system_process I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 7.153MB for 196624-byte allocation
07-25 16:20:18.140      383-398/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 20% free 7241K/8968K, paused 197ms, total 197ms
07-25 16:20:18.330      383-405/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 20% free 7241K/8968K, paused 188ms, total 188ms
07-25 16:20:18.340      383-405/system_process I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 7.430MB for 294932-byte allocation
07-25 16:20:18.540      383-392/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 192K, 21% free 7337K/9260K, paused 197ms, total 198ms
07-25 16:20:18.740      383-405/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 21% free 7337K/9260K, paused 195ms, total 196ms
07-25 16:20:18.740      383-405/system_process I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 7.430MB for 196652-byte allocation
07-25 16:20:18.940      383-392/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 21% free 7529K/9456K, paused 191ms, total 191ms
07-25 16:20:19.100      383-411/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel 'b2155e60 com.example.geopath/com.example.geopath.MapActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
07-25 16:20:19.100      383-411/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel 'b2155e60 com.example.geopath/com.example.geopath.MapActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-25 16:20:19.160      383-405/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 584K, 27% free 6944K/9456K, paused 221ms, total 224ms
07-25 16:20:19.170      383-594/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{b2146aa0 u0 com.example.geopath/com.example.geopath.HistorialActivity}
07-25 16:20:19.230      383-662/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b2155e60 com.example.geopath/com.example.geopath.MapActivity (server)'
07-25 16:20:19.230      383-662/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{b2155e60 u0 com.example.geopath/com.example.geopath.MapActivity}
07-25 16:20:19.590      383-398/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 166K, 25% free 7165K/9456K, paused 158ms, total 158ms
07-25 16:20:19.610      383-398/system_process I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 7.681MB for 635812-byte allocation
07-25 16:20:19.660        51-51/? D/Zygote﹕ Process 1307 terminated by signal (11)
07-25 16:20:19.780      383-392/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 23% free 7785K/10080K, paused 172ms, total 172ms
07-25 16:20:20.240      383-566/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.example.geopath (pid 1307) has died.
07-25 16:20:20.300    1391-1391/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-25 16:20:20.320      383-566/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.example.geopath for activity com.example.geopath/.MapActivity: pid=1391 uid=10056 gids={50056, 3003, 1028, 1015}
07-25 16:20:20.730      383-398/system_process D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7fff0b0, tid 398
07-25 16:20:20.820      383-397/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 16:20:23.250      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.250      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.260      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.260      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.260      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.310      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.310      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.320      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.320      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.320      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.360      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.360      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.380      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.380      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.380      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.380      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.390      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.390      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.390      383-427/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.390      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-25 16:20:23.390      383-427/system_process W/AudioService﹕ onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
07-25 16:20:25.980    1391-1391/com.example.geopath D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 81K, 6% free 2901K/3060K, paused 54ms, total 57ms
07-25 16:20:26.180    1391-1391/com.example.geopath I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 20.703MB for 18662416-byte allocation
07-25 16:20:26.230    1391-1400/com.example.geopath D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 1% free 21123K/21288K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
07-25 16:20:27.740      383-398/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
07-25 16:20:28.550    1391-1391/com.example.geopath D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 21136K/21288K, paused 37ms, total 38ms
07-25 16:20:28.600    1391-1391/com.example.geopath I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 24.934MB for 4426832-byte allocation
07-25 16:20:28.680    1391-1400/com.example.geopath D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 25459K/25612K, paused 72ms, total 72ms
07-25 16:20:29.250    1391-1391/com.example.geopath D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 25460K/25612K, paused 57ms, total 58ms
07-25 16:20:29.300    1391-1391/com.example.geopath I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 29.157MB for 4426832-byte allocation
07-25 16:20:29.790    1391-1391/com.example.geopath D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 29783K/29936K, paused 71ms, total 74ms
07-25 16:20:30.660     501-1411/com.android.inputmethod.latin I/LatinIME:LogUtils﹕ Dictionary info: dictionary = contacts.en_US.dict ; version = ? ; date = ?
07-25 16:20:30.800      383-397/system_process E/WindowManager﹕ Starting window AppWindowToken{b2133688 token=Token{b2105748 ActivityRecord{b2131d70 u0 com.example.geopath/.MapActivity t2}}} timed out
07-25 16:20:30.920    1391-1391/com.example.geopath D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7e63498, tid 1391
07-25 16:20:31.020    1391-1391/com.example.geopath W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-25 16:20:31.040    1391-1391/com.example.geopath D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-25 16:20:31.210      383-568/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1307 uid 10056
07-25 16:20:31.280      501-523/com.android.inputmethod.latin W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-25 16:20:33.870      383-397/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.geopath/.MapActivity: +13s619ms
```

This is my Map Activity code:

```
public class MapViewActivity extends Activity
{
    private MobileServiceClient svcClient;
    private MobileServiceTable<GeoRecord> GeoRecordTable;

    public final static String SELECTED_MARKER_ITEM = "com.example.geopath.MARKERLOCATIONID";

    private List<GeoRecord> marks = new ArrayList<GeoRecord>();

    private TextView lblMapCompanyName;
    private TextView tvTitle;
    MarkerOptions markerOpt;
    Marker marker;

    SessionManager session;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    HashMap<Marker, GeoRecord> customMarkerMap = new HashMap();

    String userId;
    String currentCompanyId;
    String companyName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);

        lblMapCompanyName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMapCompanyName);
        tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

        session = new SessionManager(MapViewActivity.this);
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserSessionInfo();
        HashMap<String, String> company = session.getUserCompanyInfo();
        userId = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERID);
        currentCompanyId = company.get(SessionManager.KEY_ENTERPRISE_ID);
        companyName = company.get(SessionManager.KEY_ENTERPRISE_NAME);

        initializeMap();

        try
        {
            svcClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "https://mobilewebsite.azure-mobile.net/",
                    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", this);
            GeoRecordTable = svcClient.getTable(GeoRecord.class);

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            createAndShowDialog(new Exception(getResources().getString(R.string.error_mobile_service)), "Error");
        }

        lblMapCompanyName.setText(companyName);


        if(hasNetworkConnection())
        {
            getUserAndCompanyRecords();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MapViewActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.validation_internet_connection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void initializeMap()
    {
        if (googleMap == null)
        {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.historyMap)).getMap();
            googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    //GeoRecord item = (GeoRecord) customMarkerMap.get(marker.getId());
                    GeoRecord item = customMarkerMap.get(marker);
                    String pId = item.getId();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MapViewActivity.this, DetalleLocalizacionActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(SELECTED_MARKER_ITEM, pId);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            if (googleMap == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.general_loading_map_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }



    public void addMarksToMap()
    {
        double tempLatitude;
        double tempLongitude;



        for(GeoRecord record : marks)
        {
            //customMarkerMap = new HashMap();
            tempLatitude = record.getLatitude();
            tempLongitude = record.getLongitude();

            markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(tempLatitude, tempLongitude)).title(record.getPlace());
            markerOpt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

            marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOpt);
            customMarkerMap.put(marker, record);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }

    private void createAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title) {

        createAndShowDialog(exception.toString(), title);
    }

    private void createAndShowDialog(String message, String title) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please? Thank you!!

Comment: Turn off the logcat filter - you don't seem to be capturing the native stack dump, as evidenced by the fact that you see the program restart in a new PID with no intervening messages.

Comment: Ok, I have posted the LogCat with no filters

Comment: Are you using NDK in your app by any chance? Could you also post your MapActivity source code?

Comment: No, just Java, no NDK

Comment: The native code here comes form the OpenGL implementation on the device, where something goes wrong as the thread is shut down.  I'd be curious if the problem will occur on a 4.3 emulator or only on 4.4  Trying to decide if changes made in response to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68923 could be related

Comment: Ok, but it seems that there is no official documentation for this issue, right?

Comment: I think your issue is in this line: 
1307-1307/com.example.geopath W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 07-25 16:20:14.110


google for "eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented" and you'll probably find a solution.

Comment: @josher932 any solution?

Comment: Hi, it happened only in the Android Virtual Device that I was using. I created another one with the same Android version and everything was OK

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the manifest file

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowClearUserData="true" >
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    /*something like an intent or an animation*/
}
```

then it won't crash on the emulator.